# need expert opinion - mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need expert evaluation concerning created queries. There is collection `"myresults"` with documents of such view:

```
{
    "_id": 0,
    "name": "aimee Zank",
    "scores": [{
    "type": "exam",
    "score": 1.463179736705023
    }, {
    "type": "quiz",
    "score": 11.78273309957772
    }, {
    "type": "homework",
    "score": 6.676176060654615
    }, {
    "type": "homework",
    "score": 35.8740349954354
    }]
}
```

Task:

1. To write query for searching all students, which have "score" > 93 and < 95 in any "type".
2. To write aggregate query in order to select the students, which have "exam" result > 90.
3. To add the field "accepted" with `value = true` for student Dan Doe.

Solution:

1.

```
db.myresults.find({
$or: [{
    $and: [{
        "scores.type": "exam"
    }, {
        "scores.score": {
            $gt: 93
        }
    }, {
        "scores.score": {
            $lt: 95
        }
    }]
}, {
    $and: [{
        "scores.type": "quiz"
    }, {
        "scores.score": {
            $gt: 93
        }
    }, {
        "scores.score": {
            $lt: 95
        }
    }]
}, {
    $and: [{
        "scores.type": "homework"
    }, {
        "scores.score": {
            $gt: 93
        }
    }, {
        "scores.score": {
            $lt: 95
        }
    }]
}]
})
```

2.

```
db.myresults.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$scores"
}, {
    $match: {
    $and: [{
        type: "exam"
    }, {
        score: {
            $gt: 90
        }
    }]
    }
}])
```

3. `db.myresults.update({name: "Dan Doe"}, {$set: {accepted: true}})`

P.S. "accepted" is added successfully in third task... but when selecting it turns out that Dan Doe is two... and "accepted" is written only in first...???

Comment: you are only facing problem at the 3rd task?

Comment: not only 3rd task... selecting results 1 and 2 show some strange output as well...

Comment: **Regarding point 2**: What is the expected resulting document of your query? Just names of the students, or additionally all *exam* scores for that student greater than 90? **Regarding point 3**: Are you sure you want to make updates using `name` as a key? I mean are you just expecting to set the `accepted` field to all documents with `name` `"Dan Doe"`?